# Including more crtieria to if statement on Apex class

Tags: apex, visualforce, formula, class

I need some help

I have an apex class which needs amending so it works on more than one criteria. Currently the class works if “Type” Contains the word “Meeting”. But I also need it to include the following;

Call – outbound
Call – inbound
Other - see subject

```
{
        System.debug('##### task type is : ' + this.thisTask.Type);
        if (this.thisTask.Type != null && this.thisTask.Type.containsIgnoreCase('Meeting')) // per requirements, the subject should contain meeting for attendees to be added to a task
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: have a look at apex operators https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the way I can think of, Declare this set (validTypeSet ) at the top of the method.

```
Set<String> validTypeSet = new Set<String>();
validTypeSet.add('Meeting');
validTypeSet.add('Call – outbound');
validTypeSet.add('Call – inbound');
validTypeSet.add('Other - see subject');

System.debug('##### task type is : ' + this.thisTask.Type);
    if (this.thisTask.Type != null && validTypeSet.containsIgnoreCase(this.thisTask.Type)) // per requirements, the subject should contain meeting for attendees to be added to a task
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```