# Updating Picklist value trigger

Tags: trigger, picklist, tasks

I need some help creating a trigger

Aim : Every time a task is created which meets criteria ( See below) then change the status from “Not started” to “Completed”

The trigger should only fire if it meets the following criteria :

```
RecordTypeId = '0123000000007ZoAAI'
Type.contains 'meeting:'
Type.contains 'Call;'
Type = 'Other - see subject'
Assigned to = 00E30000000gYL8
```

I have attempted to create the following trigger , but I am not sure if I am on the correct lines

```
trigger UpdateStatus on Task (after insert) {

   for (Task t : trigger.new){
            if (t.RecordTypeId == '0123000000007ZoAAI'){
            if (t.Type.contains('meeting:')){
            if (t.Type.contains ('Call;'))
            if (t.Type = 'Other - see subject';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}


// Need to include assigned to role/
if(t.Owner_Role__c == '00E30000000gYL8'){

Status = 'Completed':
```

Comment: The Assigned To field on [Task](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm)  is the `OwnerId` field not `Owner_Role__c`. Your [other question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66842/including-more-crtieria-to-if-statement-on-apex-class) is very similar and the comments on it have details on how to add your IF conditions together into a single line.

Comment: I can do this by workflow, i dont know why i suggested the trigger route, sorry to waste your time